# Multilevel models and correcting for multiple comparisons

Tags: multiple-comparisons, multilevel-analysis, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am conducting a study where there are three different DVs. For each DV I will be conducting a multilevel model with 2 predictors and will be interested in both main effects and interactions between the predictors.

I will be running simple effects analyses if there are significant interactions in my models to explore these interactions further, which I will correct for using a holm bonferroni procedure.

However, my question is for the main MLMs. Specifically, do I need to correct for the number of models I am running (i.e., 4) or correct for all of the parameters in each model (i.e., 8 main effects and 8 interactions)?

I have read that correcting for multiple comparisons is not needed when using a multilevel model: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/multiple2f.pdf

However, I am not sure if this applies when running more than one multilevel model.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: It is good that you are thinking this through.  Still, knowledgeable people frequently disagree when it comes to the necessity of, merits of, and best choice of multiple-comparison adjustments.  The best discussion of this topic I have seen is in Geoffrey Keppel's book *Design and Analysis:  A Researcher's Handbook*.